# python parsing characters out of a list of URLs

Tags: python, parsing

I'm new to python and working with a list of URLs I've scraped.  Some of the URLs are being returned with a `#` sign in front of it, how can i remove this?

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)


records = []
for results in links:
    url = results['href']
    records.append(url)

#here i am removing the duplicate URL's from the records list
records = set(records)
records = list(records)

#here i am returning URL's only containing 'http'
filter_records = [k for k in records if 'http' in k]

import csv
with open ('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer.writerow(['Web Address'])
    [csv_writer.writerow([record]) for record in filter_records]
```

How do i remove the `#` from some of the results in the list?

Comment: quick way to remove `#` from start of `url` will be `if url.startswith('#'): url = url[1:]`

Comment: Even quicker way: `url.lstrip('#')`

Comment: The `#foobar` links are internal links to other parts of the page. Do you want to remove just the `#` character, or the whole "URL" (if it starts with `#`)?

Comment: Why do you think that the "#" isn't part of the URL?

Comment: thanks all, the url.lstrip('#') worked perfect, and then i used url.rstrip('/') to further remove some duplicate urls being listed, one had the '/' on the end, and one didn't